Name of the direct image functor
For any map, we have the inverse image with two adjoints: the image which is the left adjoint, and the "forall" operator which is the right adjoint. This applies pretty generally. However, for toposes the direct image functor is the right adjoint of the inverse image functor.
Is there a reason the direct image functor has this name? What's the exact connection of it to "images"? There is this question but I'm entirely unconvinced of the answer, perhaps because it's too short. Generalizing from locales, sheaves are supposed to be a categorification of opens (indeed, opens are just subsingleton-valued sheaves). So there seems to be no reason for an inverted relation.
